# Android - How to use custom spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have extended the spinner class in order to customize it, but i can't figure out how to use it in my code.

```
public class mySpinner extends Spinner {
......
}
```

I have an existing activity that uses a spinner and I want to change it to use mySpinner class.

Originally:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) textEntryView
            .findViewById(R.id.account_spinner);
```

and

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/account_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/ADALabel1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/newassetsymbol"
    android:layout_below="@+id/assetclass_spinner" />
```

first I tried:

```
    mySpinner spinner = (Spinner) textEntryView
            .findViewById(R.id.account_spinner);
```

compile error (makes sense).
then I tried:

```
    mySpinner spinner = (mySpinner) textEntryView
            .findViewById(R.id.account_spinner);
```

runtime cast error.
Then I changed the layout with the previous line:

```
 <mySpinner
    android:id="@+id/account_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/ADALabel1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/newassetsymbol"
    android:layout_below="@+id/assetclass_spinner" />
```

01-12 06:50:02.664: E/AndroidRuntime(597): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.mySpinner in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.sample.sample-1.apk]

This does not seem thst hard but I am missing something.  Can someone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using custom `View` components in XML, you need to use the complete class path.

```
<com.example.appname.mySpinner />
```